# Xtext 2.0 maven or ant project

Tags: ant, maven, xtext

I want to build my own xtext 2.0 project from command line.
Could anybody share real working xtext 2.0 maven pom.xml or ant build.xml file?

Comment: xtext 2.2 has maven support: http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/xtext-2-2-finally-brings-maven-support-for-xtend/

Answer (score 2):

do you know http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/spray/. they build Xtext projects using Maven Tycho.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Maven archetype that creates an Xtext project with a multi module Maven layout and Tycho (manifest-first approach):
https://github.com/fuinorg/emt-xtext-archetype

Answer (score 0):

Several projects that you could refer to:

https://github.com/xtext-dev/maven-xtext-example
a standard maven-xtext sample using tycho, including maven pom settings and example project. I built my xtext project following this guide.

https://github.com/aphethean/xtext-maven-examples
It'll help if you wanna write your own main class.

Also,
https://github.com/applause/applause
It's not a maven xtext project, but a very good example to show how to separate grammar core and code generator logics.

Hope this would help. :)